# KIE-WB Source Code

Tags: jboss, jbpm, kie, kie-wb

It is possible to edit jbpm-console-ng as the source is given on github. What I want to know is, can you get the source code for kie-wb as well? All I can see is the distribution wars for it...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KIE Workbench is just a distribution (a collection of packages bundled together). It doesn't contain all the code for all the screens contained. The kie-wb is the sum of the jbpm console ng repo + the drools-wb repository, and of course all the dependencies from those repositories.

So if you identify the screen that you want to modify, you just need to go to the repo where that screen is defined, change that project and then build it. Now if you want to create a new distribution of the kie-wb with your changes you just need to build the kie-wb-webapp and the distributions wars for it.

HTH

Comment: so basically i have to edit the pom file in kid-wb webapp to get my local jbpm-console-ng instead of downloading it from the repository?

Comment: No, it seems that you need to read more about maven. If you compile locally your clone/fork of the jbpm console ng, when you build kie-wb it will pick up your local jars. Because we are using snapshots (which means that it will download all the nightly builds everyday), you will need to compile your local changes in the console and recompile kie-wb every time that you want to get one custom build.